# Theme search-result pages individually?

Tags: search

We can theme the search-result pages within `search-results.tpl.php` and `search-result.tpl.php`. But as far at it is possible to create multiple search pages(e.g. in apache solr module), is it possible to theme each page individually?

Example:

```
search-results--page1.tpl.php
search-results--page2.tpl.php
```

Comment: but when it displays one or the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible.

Apache solr search module introduced tpl files for each search page.

If your custom search page's machine name is simple search, the search results tpl for that page will be named as

```
    search-results--apachesolr-search--simple-search.tpl.php
```

Replace *simple-search* with the machine name of your search page, with underscores converted to hyphens.